# Stuck at spacing stick evenly in a dynamic hamburger menu in react using tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Here's my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-field-xi4ks6?file=/src/Hamburger.js).

I used [this](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/wip-hamburger-menu-animation) as the source code and converted it to react.

As you can see, I'm trying to create a dynamic hamburger menu that can get two props:

- `containerStyle`
- `stickStyle`

And the behavior should be the same for all of them, including `transition` and `duration`.

I'm stuck at spacing sticks inside the parent. If I remove the `absolute` positioning for sticks, they won't align. And when I use the `absolute` I don't know how to evenly space them.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd add the appropriate code to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and to show an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @EdLucas, I have coded an entier example that works. I have linked to it.